# 500 internal server error while installing

Tags: database, installation

What is the reason for the error "500 internal server error" while trying to install drupal,

1. i have created database successfully
2. After that i have downloaded and extracted the drupal 7.22 in my desired        directory.

But when i trying to install the tables in my database its showing  the error and approximately more than 30 tables are storing and the installation process stops automatically with showing the above error . Can anybody tell me why the error is coming.

Comment: increase execution time in php.ini

Comment: 500 is an HTTP status code, you'll need to find the underlying error by looking through the server log files. Until you have the specific error that's occurring it will be impossible for anyone here to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clive says above, it's nearly impossible to help without knowing more about your particular setup and debug info.

Common pitfalls are :

- Various php.ini settings : `max_execution_time` as mentioned by monymirza above, but also `memory_limit`. This last can be raised during install and dev, then lowered for production.
- Lacking `.htaccess` at Drupal's root. Standard unix commands often don't copy hidden files, and `.htaccess` is more or less mandatory for D7 to work.
- Lousy DB connection, particularly on shared hosting.
- Misconfigured vhost : perhaps a particular setting messes up things between domains, or subdomains. Also, you have to check the `AllowOverride All` directive on Drupal directory for it to function properly.

There are others, but these should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those hints.

In my instance, the site was installed on a Virtual Host inside Virtualmin/Webmin, which contains symbolic links in the public folder pointing to "awstatsicons".

The Drupal .htaccess file contains a directive to follow symbolic links in the installation directory:

```
# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
  Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Commenting out the Options +FollowSymLinks allowed the installation script to run:

```
# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
# Options +FollowSymLinks
```

However, I subsequently learned that Drupal needs to be able to follow Symlinks to work, so changing that to:

```
# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
# Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

This needs to be repeated in the .htaccess located at sites/default/files seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete/move all of the modules to another place. Then try to move back again one by one and try to see the output. In this way bring back all the modules and try to see the output. Then most probably you will be done or atleast you may know the module which making problem.